# Javascript sending values to PHP works second click

Tags: javascript, html

Currently, I need to take the results from the first input and move these to the second, then automatically click a button to submit them. I have 2 different functions, one works and one only works if you select it twice. I can't workout why the second click works but not the first, I tried making the function loop till it worked, automatically calling again but this also didn't work. My code below, the "booked_location" is the one that needs to be selected twice while the "awc" slctedRule works perfectly fine. The function CopyDataToExclude is called upon a button click.

I fully understand there are better ways to do what I am trying, however for the sake of changing modular components I cannot change this is what I need to do.

*Please note these are in a form, I am just showing snippets of code*

HTML for selecting the optin and button :

```
<tr>
  <td value="selection" id="booked_location_click" onclick="SelectElement('rule', 'booked_location');toggletdDisplay('booked_location');selectedRule('booked_location');">
    <b>Booked at Location</b>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="display:" value="selection" onclick="SelectElement('rule', 'awc');toggletdDisplay('awc');selectedRule('awc');">
    <b>AWC Newsletter</b>
  </td>
</tr>
<td><input class="button" type="button" name="activateExclude" id="activateExclude" onclick="CopyDataToExclude();" value="  Add To Excluded -->  " /></td>
```

Javascript :

```
window.slctedRule = "null";

//Sets the variable slctedRule to a global variable to be used elsewhere
function selectedRule(clickedSelection){
    window.slctedRule = clickedSelection;
    console.log("Selected Rule = " + window.slctedRule);
    return clickedSelection;
}


function CopyDataToExclude(){
    if ( slctedRule == "null")
    {
        console.log("SlctedRule is null not doing anything");
        return;
    }
    //BOOKED LOCATION RULE CHANGE
    else if (slctedRule == "booked_location")
        {
            //Take the drop down value and save to tempResult
            var excldBkedLcation = document.getElementById('selected_booked_location').value;

            console.log("excldBkedLcation = " + excldBkedLcation);

            //Display the exclude rule
            SelectElement('remove_rule', 'exclude_booked_location');
            togglerdDisplay('exclude_booked_location');

            //Changing the new exclude value
            document.getElementById('selected_remove_booked_location').value = excldBkedLcation;

            //Value that is changed
            var checkResult = document.getElementById('selected_remove_booked_location').value;

            console.log("checkResult = " + checkResult);


            if (checkResult == excldBkedLcation){
                console.log("Run all the way - data the same");
                document.getElementById('addExcludeButton').click();
            }
            else {
                //IF values don't match, go back to first screen and select again
                console.log("Running again - Not the same");
                document.getElementById('booked_location_click').click()
            }


            return;

        }
        //AWC RULE CHANGE
    else if (slctedRule == "awc")
        {
            if (document.getElementById('awc_yes').checked){
                tempResult = "True";
            }
            else if (document.getElementById('awc_no').checked){
                tempResult = "False";
            }
            console.log("temp result = " + tempResult);

            //Calls the exclude method, displaying the exclude data
            togglerdDisplay('exclude_awc');
            SelectElement('remove_rule', 'exclude_awc');

            //Sets the view variables to previously selected
            if (tempResult == "True"){
                radiobtn = document.getElementById("exclude_awc_yes");
                radiobtn.checked = true;
            }
            if (tempResult == "False"){
                radiobtn = document.getElementById("exclude_awc_no");
                radiobtn.checked = true;
            }
            console.log("~Run all the way");
            //Clicks the hidden exclude button automatically 
            clickExcludeBtn();
        }
}
```

The console : First run through it doesn't copy the excldBkedLcation to checkResult, however the second run through it does? Doing nothing differently, just clicking the button after making the same selection.

```
    Display the Add Rule
    Selected Rule = new_booked_event
    Display the Add Rule
    Selected Rule = booked_location
    slctedRule is = booked_location
    excldBkedLcation = 1040
    Display The Exclude View
    checkResult = 
    Running again - Not the same



    Display the Add Rule
    Selected Rule = booked_location
    Display the Add Rule
    Selected Rule = booked_location
    slctedRule is = booked_location
    excldBkedLcation = 1040
    Display The Exclude View
    checkResult = 1040
    Run all the way - data the same
```

Comment: Your included function doesnt show what happens at the start when `slctedRule === "new_booked_event"`.

Comment: @Craicerjack the new_booked_event isn't relevant, the test and console view was for the booked_location, it only appeared because new_booked_event is the default start. Whenever an onclick is triggered, it displays what it is in console and doesn't do anything with it until another button is clicked

Comment: How do you know the `new_booked_event` isnt relevant? Its where the program starts and in your console log from above its the difference between a working version and a non-working version. If the `slctedRule` starts with `new_booked_event` then none of the code in `CopyDataToExclude()` is going to run.

Comment: The question is missing some important information. When and how is `slctedRule` set? and when and how is `CopyDataToExclude()` called?

Comment: @Craicerjack I have a list with each element having an onclick function that sends the name of the clicked line to a function that stores it as a global variable (I know, global variables bad). E.g. selectedRule('new_booked_event'); so all it is doing is showing me in the console what is selected and each time a new one is selected it is copied over the last. This is where slctedRule is set

Comment: the CopyDataToExclude() method is called when the user selectes an option in the list and then clicks a button. They select first as this sends the slctedRule through and then calls the function

Comment: Well you should probably include that code becuase it doesnt look likes its working the way you expect it to. It doesnt seem to be setting `slctedRule` before the function is called.

Comment: @Craicerjack it does work as I expect as the other function that does the same but with Radio buttons and works fine. This one works too, just after the second click. I have tried to only include the nessecery code as there is quite a lot of unrelated. One moment and Ill include how they are called.

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle to work? I started one here - https://jsfiddle.net/cznh9abp/ but getting many errors. The main one right now being related to this line - `            var excldBkedLcation = document.getElementById('selected_booked_location').value;`. It doesnt exist. I created a a `td` to house it but still getting errors. You should only include code necessary for the problem at hand. Right now you have functions like `togglerdDisplay` and `SelectElement` that dont seem to be related, plus radio button stuff.